# How can I tell Windows XP/7 not to switch threads during a certain segment of my code?

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi

I want to prevent a thread switch by Windows XP/7 in a time critical part of my code that runs in a background thread.  I'm pretty sure I can't create a situation where I can guarantee that won't happen, because of higher priority interrupts from system drivers, etc.  However, I'd like to decrease the probability of a thread switch during that part of my code to the minimum that I can.  Are there any create-thread flags or Window API calls that can assist me?  General technique tips are appreciated too.  If there is a way to get this done without having to raise the threads priority to real-time-critical that would be great, since I worry about creating system performance issues for the user if I do that.

UPDATE: I am adding this update after seeing the first responses to my original post.  The concrete application that motivated the question has to do with real-time audio streaming.  I want to eliminate every bit of delay I can.  I found after coding up my original design that a thread switch can cause a 70ms or more delay at times.  Since my app is between two sockets acting as a middleman for delivering audio, the instant I receive an audio buffer I want to immediately turn around and push it out the the destination socket.  My original design used two cooperating threads and a semaphore since the there was one thread managing the source socket, and another thread for the destination socket.  This architecture evolved from the fact the two devices behind the sockets are disparate entities.

I realized that if I combined the two sockets onto the same thread I could write a code block that reacted immediately to the socket-data-received message and turned it around to the destination socket in one shot.   Now if I can do my best to avoid an intervening thread switch, that would be the optimal coding architecture for minimizing delay.  To repeat, I know I can't guarantee this situation, but I am looking for tips/suggestions on how to write a block of code that does this and minimizes as best as I can the chance of an intervening thread switch.

Note, I am aware that O/S code behind the sockets introduces (potential) delays of its own.

Comment: That's not possible.  If anything, you'll want to *increase* the odds that there will be a thread context switch.  So you can find the threading bugs quicker.  Use random sleeps in the debug build.

Comment: What if two threads did this?

Comment: @HansPassant - See the update to my post.

Comment: You can't do much to prevent context switches, thread suspension etc., other than increasing the priority of your thread. The normal way to solve your problem is using buffering techniques.

Comment: Audio bandwidth is not that large, these days, and RAM is plentiful.  I find it difficult to understand how a semahore-based, (or indeed, a queue based on any counter), queue could fail to keep up with audio buffers.  70ms is a long time in inter-thread comms.  If a semaphore signal makes a thread ready and it regularly does not run for 70ms plus, you have some serious overload on that box, but ocasionally, it's not unusual if other apps are running.  Can you not get away with maintaining 100ms of buffering on the output side?

Comment: Buffers add delay.  I already have a 100ms buffer to smooth the audio playback but I am trying to winnow that down.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK there are no such flags in `CreateThread` or etc (This also doesn't make sense IMHO). You may snooze other threads in your process from execution during in critical situations (by enumerating them and using `SuspendThread`), as well as you theoretically may enumerate & suspend threads in other processes.

OTOH snoozing threads is generally not a good idea, eventually you may call some 3rd-party code that would implicitly wait for something that should be accomplished in another threads, which you suspended.

IMHO - you should use what's suggested for the case - playing with thread/process priorities (also you may consider `SetThreadPriorityBoost`). Also the OS tends to raise the priority to threads that usually don't use CPU aggressively. That is, threads that work often but for short durations (before calling one of the waiting functions that suspend them until some condition) are considered to behave "nicely", and they get prioritized.